# Secure important keys/config in Spring application

Tags: java, security, key, jwt

I have private/public keys which is used to signing JWT. All keys are in file on a disc/server (saved while application is deployed). 
To secure this file - I encode it. 
The keys decryption procedure is as follows:

--> use Encryptor class in my app which use AES algorithm to decode/encode.
--> have a file with encoded password (password.property). This file is ONLY on the serwer (no in the app)

To decode keys I have to decode password from my file (password.property) and then use this decoded password do decode keys. Thanks to this solution I have no password/key to keys in my application/repository.

Do you use patterns like this? What is the best file format to store keys and password do decode keys?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a solution like [Spring Vault](http://projects.spring.io/spring-vault/)? See [examples](https://github.com/mp911de/spring-cloud-vault-config-samples)